# How to determine the number of inherited handles in a process?

Tags: windows

I'd like to count the number of inheritable handles that will be inherited by a child process using [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) with `bInheritHandles=TRUE`

> [in] bInheritHandles
>
> If this parameter is TRUE, each inheritable handle in the calling
> process is inherited by the new process. If the parameter is FALSE,
> the handles are not inherited.

So far, I've tried the following code to

- Count all inherited handles in the process.
- Create 1000 inheritable events.
- Recount the handles.

Unfortunately, the output from the code below is incorrect (not sure why?)

```
BEFORE: Number of inherited handles: 3802
AFTER: Number of inherited handles: 3804
```

However, [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows the correct before/after handles count:

[image: PE]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SystemHandleInformation 16
#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 0x10000
#define INHERITED_HANDLE_FLAG 0x1

typedef struct {
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct {
    ULONG HandleCount;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef UINT(CALLBACK* PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO)(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);

int GetInheritedHandleCount() {
    SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION* handleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)malloc(INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
    ULONG handleInfoSize = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    int inheritedHandleCount = 0;

    PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO NtQuerySystemInformation = (PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    while (NtQuerySystemInformation((SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)SystemHandleInformation, handleInfo, handleInfoSize, NULL) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
        handleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);
    }

    for (ULONG i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++) {
        if (handleInfo->Handles[i].Flags & INHERITED_HANDLE_FLAG) {
            inheritedHandleCount++;
        }
    }

    free(handleInfo);
    return inheritedHandleCount;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("BEFORE: Number of inherited handles: %u\n", GetInheritedHandleCount());
    getchar();

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;  // Make handles inheritable

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        CreateEvent(&sa, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    printf("AFTER: Number of inherited handles: %u\n", GetInheritedHandleCount());
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

**Workaround**

[Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)

**Question**

Is there a way to list how many handles a child process will inherit from its parent?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. The changes to the original code are:

1. `NtQuerySystemInformation` with the `SystemHandleInformation (16)` class retrieves handle information for ALL processes running on the system, not just the current process. Added checks for current PID only.
2. `GetHandleInformation` checks the inheritability of handles within the current process. Added the following flag check:

> HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT - If this flag is set, a child process
> created with the bInheritHandles parameter of CreateProcess set to
> TRUE will inherit the object handle.

The output is much better now and shows the 1000 inheritable event handles:

```
BEFORE: Number of inherited handles: 3
...
Handle: 0x1050, Object Type: Event, Num: 19
Handle: 0x1054, Object Type: Event, Num: 19
Handle: 0x1058, Object Type: Event, Num: 19
...
AFTER: Number of inherited handles: 1003
```

Here's the updated code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

#define SystemHandleInformation 16
#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 0x10000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct {
    ULONG HandleCount;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef UINT(CALLBACK* PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO)(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION {
    UNICODE_STRING TypeName;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;

NTSTATUS NTAPI NtQueryObject(
    HANDLE Handle,
    OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS ObjectInformationClass,
    PVOID ObjectInformation,
    ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
);

NTSTATUS GetObjectTypeName(USHORT handle, BYTE ObjectTypeNumber) {
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG returnLength;
    UNICODE_STRING *objectName;
    OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION* objectTypeInfo;
    PVOID buffer;

    buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (!buffer) return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

    status = NtQueryObject((HANDLE)handle, (OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS)ObjectTypeInformation, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &returnLength);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        objectTypeInfo = (OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION*)buffer;
        objectName = &objectTypeInfo->TypeName;
        size_t copyLength = (objectName->Length / sizeof(WCHAR) < 259) ? (objectName->Length / sizeof(WCHAR)) : 259;
        wchar_t typeName[260];
        wcsncpy_s(typeName, 260, objectName->Buffer, copyLength);

        if (wcscmp(typeName, L"Event") == 0) {
            printf("Handle: 0x%04x, Object Type: %wZ, Num: %u\n", handle, objectName, ObjectTypeNumber);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    return status;
}


int GetInheritedHandleCount() {
    ULONG currentProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION* handleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)malloc(INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
    ULONG handleInfoSize = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    int inheritedHandleCount = 0;
    DWORD dwFlags;

    PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO NtQuerySystemInformation = (PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFO)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

    while (NtQuerySystemInformation((SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)SystemHandleInformation, handleInfo, handleInfoSize, NULL) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) {
        handleInfo = (SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION*)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);
    }

    for (ULONG i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++) {
        if (handleInfo->Handles[i].ProcessId == currentProcessId) {
            if (GetHandleInformation((HANDLE)handleInfo->Handles[i].Handle, &dwFlags)) {
                if (dwFlags & HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT) {
                    inheritedHandleCount++;
                    GetObjectTypeName(handleInfo->Handles[i].Handle, handleInfo->Handles[i].ObjectTypeNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    free(handleInfo);
    return inheritedHandleCount;
}

int main() {
    printf("BEFORE: Number of inherited handles: %u\n", GetInheritedHandleCount());
    getchar();

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;  // Make handles inheritable!

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        CreateEvent(&sa, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    printf("AFTER: Number of inherited handles: %u\n", GetInheritedHandleCount());
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```